# Powershell script for searching for a specific program and then output if it is installed or not

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I am trying to write a script to search a local PC for a specific program and if it has that specific program, then output text saying "Specific Program is installed". If it does not have that specific program, then output text saying "Specific Program is not installed".

I currently have this below but it seems not to work. It keeps spitting out that the program is not installed even when it is installed. Can someone help me out and see what im doing wrong.

This is not a duplicate as i have already searched for answers on here.

```
$list | ForEach-Object{
    $computer = $_
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $computer | 
            Select-Object -Property Name | 
            Sort-Object Name | 
            Where-Object{$_.Name -match "FireEye Endpoint Agent"} | 
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $computer -passthru
}
If ($_.Name -eq "FireEye Endpoint Agent"){
    "FireEye is installed"
}
Else{
    "FireEye is not installed"
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement is outside the pipeline. What do you expect `$_` to be?

Comment: [`Win32_Product` is evil](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/). **DO NOT** use it for enumerating installed programs.

Comment: Im not sure, im super new to Powershell and thought that i could use google to my advantage to sort of understand what i can use it for. I just know what im trying to get to and i obviously cant lol. So far, it outputs FireEye Endpoint Agent and the computer name so im guessing that the $_ is the computer name. Im just trying to modify this to where i can also output text saying "program is installed" or "program is not installed"

Comment: @andrew91_dm If it does not have to be in powershell, I can wright you a very simple batch script that can do what you need.